# What is the phrase for when you learn that there is so many things you didn't know?

Tags: word-request

I'm trying to make a sentence and convey the meaning that ignorance is bliss but I learned that there were this many things I didn't know and then learned about the things I didn't know about but I'm just looking for how to say that I learned all the things that I didn't know in a concise way.

Basically
what is it called when you learn that there is so many things you didn't know?

Comment: to fill one's knowledge gaps....

Comment: I don't know that we have a single phrase to express your feeling.  It most likely will be said many ways, each wrapped in a favorite regional or familial saying.  I like, "The older I get, the less I know."  This roughly translates as - "The more things I learn, the more I realize how many things I don't know."

Comment: silly answer, "wisdom" "but I am wiser now"

Answer (score 0):

**Hindsight is 20/20** is a phrase that means one has (after a situation) learned things which, had they been known at the time, would have led to different choices.

Comment: This just doesn't answer the question, which is not about regret....

Answer (score 0):

The effect at play here is [Dunning–Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect#:%7E:text=The%20Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger%20effect%20is%20defined%20as%20the%20tendency%20of,forms%20of%20thinking%20and%20judging). I often say "hitting the second peak of the Dunning-Kruger curve" but I don't think it's in popular usage.

Another way to describe it concisely would be the popular Aristotle quote,"The more you know, the more you realize you don't know."